# WooCommerce | Make products of category only available on one day of the week

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, stock

I'm an absolute beginner in PHP and WooCommerce. Our shop sells products to businesses, but only on one day of the week each category. So I have category „Monday“, „Tuesday“ and so on. Problem is: if somebody puts a Monday-product into their shopping cart, he can buy it on Tuesday.
What I want to do is change the availability only to „available“ on the given day and change it back to „not available“ next day.

Also I don't know how to get ALL the products of one category. Here's what I tried for the Monday category. Please don't kill me …

Any help is highly appreciated! <3

```
function weekday_products() {
    $product_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'limit' => -1,
        'category' => 'Monday',
        //more options according to wc_get_products() docs
    );
    $products_monday = wc_get_products($product_args);

    if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon') {
        foreach ($products_monday as $product) {
            if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
                wc_update_product_stock_status( $product, 'instock' );
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($products_monday as $product) {
            if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
                wc_update_product_stock_status( $product, 'outofstock' );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'only_on_weekday_products', 'weekday_products' );
```

At the moment I can't try the code, because the shop is in production. But I'm pretty sure, it wouldn't work anyway …

Edit:
Another solution would be to clear the carts at midnight, so something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    $now = strtotime("now");
    $midnight = strtotime("00:00:00");
    if ( $now = $midnight ) {
        // Empty cart
        WC()->cart->empty_cart(true);
        WC()->session->set('cart', array());
    }

}
```

Does this code work?

Comment: A better option will be to fetch the current day and then apply to add to cart & cart item validation as per day logic and you can also, change can purchase status of the product dynamically using your logic. Changing the stock is not a good thing for this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I don‘t Unterstand what you mean. What am I supposed to do? Do you have a code snippet or anything for me to understand?

Comment: I dont know how you use that only_on_weekday_products hook but you should keep it not overcomplicated so i suggest using - woocommerce_product_query hook where you can check what day of week it is and load only products from that category. There are many examples here and in google about it. As for the cart use woocommerce_before_cart from which you can check what items are in cart and do your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would approach this. Place the following functions in your active theme functions.php

If you want for SEO purposes or something else to keep showing all products as they are then skip hide_products_per_day function. Only check your cart what is added to it.

```
//Show products only from specific category
function hide_products_per_day( $q ) {
    $day = date('l');
    $tax_query = $q->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug', // Query by term slug
        'terms'    => array( $day ), // In our case its current day
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products_per_day' );

function check_products_in_cart() {
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return; // Skip if cart is empty
    $day = date('l');
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( !has_term( $day, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            wc_print_notice( $cart_item['data']->get_name().' cant be purchased today!', 'error' ); // Change type of notice if you want either error, success or notice (or custome).
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout', 'check_products_in_cart' ); // In case we go straight to checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_products_in_cart' ); // We want to check what is in cart
```